# Foreach loop in java for a custom object list

Tags: java, foreach, arraylist

I have an ArrayList for type Room (my custom object) Defined as below

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
```

After then adding a series of objects to the ArrayList I want to go through them all and check various things. I am not a keen user of java but I know in many other programming languages a foreach loop would be the most simple way of doing this.

After a bit of research I found the following link which suggests the code below.
[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

```
for(Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  String item = i.next();
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

But as far as I can tell this cant be used for an Arraylist of a custom object.

Can, and if so how can I implement a foreach loop for an ArrayList of a custom object?
Or how could I otherwise process each item?

Comment: Did you try it? Of course it works with custom objects. Try it out.

Comment: google search "java foreach" brings up the following page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html A bit of research? Took me 2 seconds.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Actually the [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) should look like this

```
for (final Room room : rooms) {
          // Here your room is available
}
```

Comment: in the code above what is the 'final' for? The example below doesn't seem to have this.

Comment: Using `final` keyword is considered a good practice whenever you're using a variable which holds a constant value or a reference (like in your case) which should not change. In this `for` loop it prevents the code inside it to accidently assign a different `Room` to the `room` local variable.

Comment: @ShyJ It doesn't really add anything though. Assigning room does no harm, and making room final doesn't prevent any harm that could be done by mutating a room.

Comment: @Cubic Well, without final you could actually have a `room = new Room ()` statement in the loop body and operate on a completely different room.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use Java 8 stream API and do the same thing in one line.

If you want to print any specific property then use this syntax:

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
rooms.forEach(room -> System.out.println(room.getName()));
```

OR

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
rooms.forEach(room -> {
    // here room is available
});
```

if you want to print all the properties of Java object then use this:

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
rooms.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for(Room room : rooms) {
  //room contains an element of rooms
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this sample and the code in the other answer that includes the word 'final'?

Comment: If a variable is final, it means you can`t change it`s value.

Comment: So that while iterating you are not allowed to update its value.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your example with the iterator pattern by changing the parametrization of the class:

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
rooms.add(room1);
rooms.add(room2);
for(Iterator<Room> i = rooms.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  String item = i.next();
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

or much simpler way:

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
rooms.add(room1);
rooms.add(room2);
for(Room room : rooms) {
  System.out.println(room);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code fails to operate on every item in the list, it must be because something is throwing an exception before you have completed the list; the likeliest candidate is the method called "insertOrThrow". You could wrap that call in a try-catch structure to handle the exception for whichever items are failing without exiting the loop and the method prematurely.