# Return certain values from the arraylist

Tags: java, netbeans

Trying to return only the references(`IW1`, `SS2`) in the `getUFFleet()` however it is returning every single value of the `toString()`. Methods`getUFFleet()` and `setupForces` are from the same class while the `toString` from another class FYI.

```
public String getUFFleet()
    {
        System.out.println(ForceDetails.toString());
        
        return "No forces in UFF";
      
    }
```

```
private void setupForces()
    {
        ForceDetails.add(new starShip("IW1","Twisters",200,200,10,0,0,"No","Wing" +"\n"));
        ForceDetails.add(new starShip("SS2","Enterprise",300,200,0,10,20,"No","Starship"));
  
    }
```

```
   public String toString()
    {
        String s;
        s = "\nForce reference: " + FleetRef + "\nName: " + FullName +
            "\nActivation Fee: " + ActivationFee +"\nStrikers: "
            + Strikers + "\nLaser Canons: " + LaserCanon + "\nPhotonTorpedoes: "
            + PhotonTorpedoes + "\nStregth: "+ BattleStrength
            +"\nCloaking: " + Cloaking + "\nForce Type: " + ForceType +"\n";
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't undersand. What do you mean with `every single value of the toString()`?

Comment: @gmanjon my output is ```FleetRef``` ```FullName``` ```ActivationFee``` ```Strikers``` ```LaserCanon```etc. id like my output to be only ```FleetRef```

Comment: Isn't enough changing the `toString` method to this single line? `return "Force reference: " + FleetRef;`?

Comment: @gmanjon i need the other values for other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to loop trough:

```
public String getUFFleet(){
    ForceDetails.forEach((starShip data) -> {
        System.out.println(data.getFleetRef());
      }
    );

    return "No forces in UFF";
}
```

as extra information about forEach loops see following link:
[Foreach loop in java for a custom object list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520571/foreach-loop-in-java-for-a-custom-object-list)

Comment: in the ```getUFFleet``` method?

Comment: @Abbas did it work? if it doesn't work check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520571/foreach-loop-in-java-for-a-custom-object-list for more detailed forEach explanations and implement from the explanation.

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: is there a way for it to iterate through ```ForceDetails``` and see if the list empty, and if it is the output will be ```No such forces in UFF```.  because im getting this message although the list full

Comment: You can check if list is empty. just do something like `ForceDetails.isEmpty()` it will return a boolean value based on the condition. Check this non official link about arraylist functions from https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist

Comment: @Abbas it is also a good practice to check null or empty in first line of the function because rest of the code will not get executed if the something is empty.